# Click a certain button name so it triggers the WithEvents in Class Module

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

In the "test" worksheet, I have two ActiveX button with name btTest1 and btTest2.

In the "test" worksheet module:

```vb
Dim MyButtons As Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Set MyButtons = New Collection
For i = 1 To 2
    Set ButtonClass = New ClassTest
    If i = 1 Then Set ButtonClass.obj1 = ActiveSheet.btTest1
    If i = 2 Then Set ButtonClass.obj1 = ActiveSheet.btTest2
    MyButtons.Add ButtonClass
Next
End Sub
```

In the ClassTest class module:

```vb
Private WithEvents bt As MSForms.CommandButton

Property Set obj1(b As MSForms.CommandButton)
Set bt = b
End Property

Private Sub bt_Click()
MsgBox bt.Caption
End Sub
```

After I activate the "test" sheet, then click the "TEST 1" button it shows the msgbox "TEST 1" and when I click the "TEST 2" button it shows the msgbox "TEST 2".

*How to code so when "test" sheet is activated then the msgbox "TEST 1" directly shows as if there is a user literally click the "TEST 1" button?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add:

```
Me.btTest1.Value = True
```

to the end of your event code.

Answer (score 1):

Rory has fully answered your question, a little more depending on what you might be trying to achieve -

```
'''' worksheet module '''
Option Explicit
Private MyButtons As Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim i As Long
Dim ButtonClass As ClassTest

    If MyButtons Is Nothing Then
        Set MyButtons = New Collection
        For i = 1 To 2
            Set ButtonClass = New ClassTest
            If i = 1 Then Set ButtonClass.obj1 = Me.btTest1
            If i = 2 Then Set ButtonClass.obj1 = Me.btTest2
            MyButtons.Add ButtonClass
        Next
    End If
    
    Set ButtonClass = MyButtons(1) ' refer to the first item (a ButtonClass instance) in the collection
    
    ButtonClass.bt_Click  '

End Sub

''' ClassTest '''
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents bt As MSForms.CommandButton

Public Property Set obj1(b As MSForms.CommandButton)
Set bt = b
End Property

Public Sub bt_Click()
MsgBox bt.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: typo - 'a ButtonClass instance' should read 'a ClassTest instance', not sure why I couldn't edit it directly...!

Comment: So I copy all the codes from you. It also work as expected soon after I activate the "test" sheet, it show the msgbox. Thank your very much for another way, Peter.